# Elegant 2D numpy indexing with multiple conditions

Tags: python, numpy, data-cleaning

I have an array of numbers that I wish to turn into dummy variables (i.e. arrays with 1 if condition is met, 0 if otherwise). However, the conditions can be numerous and I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution than what I'm using.

```
arr = np.random.randint(0, 50, size=(100, 100))

# What I'm doing

dummy = np.zeros(arr.shape)
dummy[np.where(np.logical_or.reduce((arr== 10, arr== 15, arr==16, arr==17)))] = 1
```

In the example, every value that is 10, 15, 16, or 17 becomes a one else a zero. For some dummy variables I have 10+ conditions and the expression can get lengthy, so I'm looking for something cleaner. I tried something like this but got a ValueError.

```
dummy= [1 if x in [10, 15, 16, 17] else 0 for x in arr]
```

Comment: Where do you get a `ValueError`? For me, your last line works fine. However, the output is of course a `list` and not an `np.array`.

Comment: dummy= [1 if x in [10, 15, 16, 17] else 0 for x in arr]   should work. check again. In my case, it worked.

Comment: @JohanL Whoops, I accidentally made the example incorrectly- it's supposed to be a 2d array. I've fixed it and now the error pops up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Readability is a bit in the eye of the beholder, but two different ways to use the `1 in ... else 0` construct is to use a double `for` loop over the elements of the rows of the matrix as

```
dummy = [[1 if x in [10, 15, 16, 17] else 0 for x in row] for row in arr]
```

The output of this is not an `np.array` (matrix) though but rather a `list`of `list`s. Another way to do it, which "hides" the double `for` loop is to use `np.vectorize` as

```
dummy_func = np.vectorize(lambda x: 1 if x in [10, 15, 16, 17] else 0)
dummy = dummy_func(arr)
```

or as a one-liner as

```
dummy = np.vectorize(lambda x: 1 if x in [10, 15, 16, 17] else 0)(arr)
```

Of these *I* would probably go for the vectorized approach to keep the data type as an `np.array` as this is most often a more reasonable choice. And, even if I showed it as possible one-liner, I would still think it would be better to first define the function and then apply it on two different lines.

It should be noted though, that vectorize is basically just a double `for` loop, so the execution is rather slow compared to other `numpy` functions. I wouldn't be surprised if there are other ways as well, that might be able to use the built-in parallel computational behavior of `numpy` but then it is again a trade off between readability (intent) and speed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.select`

```
arr = np.select([arr==10, arr==15,arr==16,arr==17],[1,1,1,1],0)
```